# How to skip duplicate values appending into a dict value of type list

Tags: python, dictionary

Actually i have a dict of this type

```
d={'a':{'s':'100100.sss','s1':'100200.ss2','s2':'100200.333'},
  'b':{'t':'100100.yyy','u':'100100.rrr','i':'1001500ttt'},'c':{'f':'g','y':'o'}}
```

From this i am creating dict of this type

```
temp={'a':['100100','100200','100200'],'b':['100100',100100'],'c'=[]}
```

For this i am using code like this

```
temp={}
for k,v in d.items():
    temp[k]=[]
    for key,val in v.items():
    templist=val.split(".")
    if templist[0].isdigit():
            if templist[0] not in a.values():
                temp[k].append(templist[0])
            else:
                continue
```

Actually i want dict in this type

```
temp={'a':['100100','100200'],'b':['100100'],'c'=[]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    for key,val in v.items():
        fn = val.split('.')[0]
        if fn.isdigit():
            temp.setdefault(k, set()).add(fn)
print dict((k, list(v)) for k, v in temp.items())
```

prints

```
{'a': ['100100', '100200'], 'b': ['100100']}
```

or as a one-liner:

```
dict((k, list(set(e.split('.')[0] for e in v.values() if e.split('.')[0].isdigit()))) for k,v in d.items())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d={'a':{'s':'100100.sss','s1':'100200.ss2','s2':'100200.333'},
  'b':{'t':'100100.yyy','u':'100100.rrr'}}

temp = dict([(k, list(set([x.split('.')[0] for x in v.values()]))) \
       for k,v in d.items()])
```

Bit of explanation what it does. It iterates over all items in `d`, giving key/value pairs. Each value is dictionary, of which you ignore keys, thus it iterates over values. These are passed trough split. Resulting list is converted to `set`, which makes values unique, then back to list (not sure if you actually need that step). In the end the list of key, value pairs is converted back to dictionary.

Comment: Beat me in time. Great method.

Comment: you don't need two pairs of square brackets.

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk: I know, but this is hard to understand as is, w/o square brackets would be even harder.

Comment: @vartec so don't write such one-liners:)

Comment: @vartec i tried ur code, it works only if all values contains ".", if some values doesnt have "." then even that too will come. wait i will update my question

Comment: Yes you should have mentioned that in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Works only in in Python `2.7+` and `3+`

```
>>> d = {'a': {'s': '100100.sss', 's1': '100200.ss2', 's2': '100200.333'},
         'b': {'t': '100100.yyy', 'u': '100100.rrr'}}
>>> {k:{el.split('.')[0] for el in v.itervalues()} for k,v in d.iteritems()}
{'a': set(['100100', '100200']), 'b': set(['100100'])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your problem worked out in IDLE. The output is broken artificially to avoid scrolling.

```
{k: list(set([i.split('.')[0] for i in v.values()])) for k, v in d.iteritems()}

{'a': ['100100', '100200'], 
 'b': ['100100']}{'a': ['100100', '100200'], 
 'c': ['g', 'o'], 
 'b': ['100100', '1001500ttt']}
```

Comment: their is no condition to check whether "i.split('.')[0] is digit or not and i updated my dict